# Console application does not gracefully terminate if subscribed to IObservable

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

Having a console application and using Nito.AsyncEx I have the below entry point.

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = -1;
    try
    {
        result = AsyncContext.Run(() => MainAsync(args));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
    }

#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate...");
    Console.ReadKey();
#endif
    return result;
}
```

I havean `IDisposable` class exposing an `IObservable<T>` property.

```
private readonly Subject<Tuple<IReadOnlyCollection<dynamic>, string>> _onDataResultsSubject = new Subject<Tuple<IReadOnlyCollection<dynamic>, string>>();

public IObservable<Tuple<IReadOnlyCollection<dynamic>, string>> OnDataResults => _onDataResultsSubject;
```

In `MainAsync` I subscribe to the `OnDataResults` property.

```
using (var processor = new Processor())
{
    var eventDisposable = processor.OnDataResults
        .Select(tuple => Tuple.Create(DataResultsToChunks(tuple.Item1, dataChunkSize), tuple.Item2))
        .Select(tuple => DataChunksToMessageEnvelopes(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2))
        .SelectMany(messageEnvelope => PublishMessagesAsync(messageEnvelope, messagingService))
        .Subscribe(messagesSent =>
        {
            var result = messagesSent.Select(p => p.ToString())
                .Aggregate((p1, p2) => $"{p1}, {p2}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Message sent {result}");
        },
        ex => Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error: {ex}"));

    await processor.ProcessAsync(migrationConfigs).ConfigureAwait(false);

    eventDisposable.Dispose();
}
```

When application is successfully finish and the `Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate...");` is printed hitting any key does not terminate the application. Even in Release mode the console window remains open and hang.

Removing the IDisposable subscription everything works fine.

Comment: Try changing `ConfigureAwait(false)` to true?

Comment: Not sure how that helps; Can you elaborate further?

Comment: Sure, essentially RX tries its best to ensure everything runs asynchronously in the correct context, but sometimes it can get tricky, especially when mixing async / await code and RX.

`ConfigureAwait(false)` basically tells the TPL to not worry about which sync context the result of the async operation comes back on, and that can cause issues, especially as you're involving the AsyncContext from NitroEx; that's a lot of things that have to agree on the contexts to use.

I'm also curious, what is the signature of `Processor.ProcessAsync`? Does it return void or Task?

Comment: And (sorry) if you could set a breakpoint on `eventDisposable.Dispose()` and see if it ever gets hit, that would be great.

I've got a suspicion that with your code currently, it's only getting as far as the await and then baling out of the method, so the console isn't closing because it believes there's still code running (which there is).

Comment: I've changed to true and also validated that the code hits the dispose event, but still application remains running.

Comment: Oooh, a mystery, could you upload a minimum verifiable example to somewhere like GitHub that exhibits this behaviour? It would be helpful to be able to run it and poke at it myself.

Comment: Interesting thing is if I add SubscribeOn and ObserveOn it doesn't even process the results, I believe it has to do something with the stack (Console App). Not sure if I can build something to reproduce, the ProcessAsync actually goes to a DB2 database etc. I also use PunchClock to queue the tasks.

Comment: Also, one last idea, your `SelectMany` do you mean to be subscribing to every observable emitted by `PublishMessageAsync` (previous ones stay subscribed btw), or do you mean to use `Switch` to drop existing subscription and subscribe when a new value comes along?

Comment: SelectMany unwraps the Task result, in my understanding, and is just part of the sequential concatenation of the workflow. It will be invoked for each event raised.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163885/discussion-between-clint-and-george-taskos).

Comment: Shouldn't Main return void or Task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code demonstrated in the question and the suspicion caught by @clint is related to `.SelectMany(messageEnvelope => PublishMessagesAsync(messageEnvelope, messagingService))`. 
It seems that `PublishMessagesAsync` was holding to `messagingService` instance with a connection to RabbitMQ.

Since `messagingService` is my own implementation and implements `IDisposable` calling `Dispose()` and cleaning resources internally Reactive Extensions will no longer hold to the instance.

Love RX! Always push you to better programming :-)